# How to count increments and decrements in a graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, time-series

I have a dataframe in r with the sensorValue for each 5 minutes as the quantity of liters in a gas tank like so:

```
id sensorValue timeStamp delta
1   586   08-11-16 23:39   0
2   595   08-11-16 23:44   9
3   586   08-11-16 23:49   -9
4   586   08-11-16 23:55   0
5   586   08-11-16 23:59   0
6   576   09-11-16 00:04   -10
7   595   09-11-16 00:09   19
8   586   09-11-16 00:14   -9
9   586   09-11-16 00:19   0
```

with rows all the way for 2 months. Now, if i smooth (considering the gas expansion as 2% of the tank capacity, 960 liters) and ggplot the sensorValues in the time span it gives me a graph like this:

[image]

The problem is when i try to count the decrements and increments in the graph, each row pointing down have to count one decrement and each arrow pointing upwards have to count as an increment, but if you notice each row represents a 5 minute register in my dataframe, and each increment or decrement consists of more than one row, i wonder if there is a way to count the times when the tank was filled, and when the gas in the tank is being used, ignoring the normal expansion of the volume due to termal contraction or expansion.

Here is the output of dput(df[1:50,]):

```
structure(list(sensorValue = c(586, 595, 586, 586, 586, 576, 
595, 586, 586, 576, 586, 576, 576, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 595, 
586, 586, 586, 586, 576, 586, 586, 586, 595, 586, 576, 576, 586, 
586, 586, 595, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 
586, 595, 586, 586, 586), TimeStamp = structure(c(1478669973, 
1478670292, 1478670583, 1478670901, 1478671193, 1478671482, 1478671773, 
1478672092, 1478672383, 1478672673, 1478672993, 1478673283, 1478673575, 
1478673894, 1478674185, 1478674474, 1478674794, 1478675084, 1478675375, 
1478675694, 1478675985, 1478676274, 1478676594, 1478676884, 1478677175, 
1478677494, 1478677785, 1478678075, 1478678395, 1478678684, 1478678977, 
1478679295, 1478679587, 1478679876, 1478680196, 1478680486, 1478680777, 
1478681095, 1478681386, 1478681676, 1478681996, 1478682286, 1478682577, 
1478682895, 1478683186, 1478683476, 1478683796, 1478684086, 1478684377, 
1478684695), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), capacidad = c(961, 
961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 
961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 
961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 
961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961), delta = c(0, 
9, -9, 0, 0, -10, 19, -9, 0, -10, 10, -10, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
9, -9, 0, 0, 0, -10, 10, 0, 0, 9, -9, -10, 0, 10, 0, 0, 9, -9, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, -9, 0, 0), smoothValue = c(586, 
586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 576, 576, 576, 586, 
586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 
586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 
586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586)), .Names = c("sensorValue", 
"TimeStamp", "capacidad", "delta", "smoothValue"), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the output of dput(df[660:720,]):

```
structure(list(sensorValue = c(586, 595, 586, 586, 586, 576, 
595, 586, 586, 576, 586, 576, 576, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 595, 
586, 586, 586, 586, 576, 586, 586, 586, 595, 586, 576, 576, 586, 
586, 586, 595, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 
586, 595, 586, 586, 586), TimeStamp = structure(c(1478669973, 
1478670292, 1478670583, 1478670901, 1478671193, 1478671482, 1478671773, 
1478672092, 1478672383, 1478672673, 1478672993, 1478673283, 1478673575, 
1478673894, 1478674185, 1478674474, 1478674794, 1478675084, 1478675375, 
1478675694, 1478675985, 1478676274, 1478676594, 1478676884, 1478677175, 
1478677494, 1478677785, 1478678075, 1478678395, 1478678684, 1478678977, 
1478679295, 1478679587, 1478679876, 1478680196, 1478680486, 1478680777, 
1478681095, 1478681386, 1478681676, 1478681996, 1478682286, 1478682577, 
1478682895, 1478683186, 1478683476, 1478683796, 1478684086, 1478684377, 
1478684695), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), capacidad = c(961, 
961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 
961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 
961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 
961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961), delta = c(0, 
9, -9, 0, 0, -10, 19, -9, 0, -10, 10, -10, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
9, -9, 0, 0, 0, -10, 10, 0, 0, 9, -9, -10, 0, 10, 0, 0, 9, -9, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, -9, 0, 0), smoothValue = c(586, 
586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 576, 576, 576, 586, 
586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 
586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 
586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586, 586)), .Names = c("sensorValue", 
"TimeStamp", "capacidad", "delta", "smoothValue"), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(df[660:720,])
structure(list(sensorValue = c(432, 442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 
442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 432, 442, 490, 
922, 912, 922, 922, 932, 912, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 
922, 922, 932, 912, 912, 922, 922, 912, 922, 912, 922, 912, 922, 
912, 922, 922, 922, 912, 912, 912, 922, 912, 922, 922, 922, 922, 
903, 912, 912), TimeStamp = structure(c(1478867679, 1478868000, 
1478868291, 1478868582, 1478868874, 1478869195, 1478869485, 1478869777, 
1478870097, 1478870389, 1478870679, 1478871000, 1478871291, 1478871582, 
1478871874, 1478872195, 1478872485, 1478872777, 1478873097, 1478873389, 
1478873679, 1478874000, 1478874291, 1478874583, 1478874874, 1478875195, 
1478875485, 1478875777, 1478876097, 1478876389, 1478876679, 1478877000, 
1478877291, 1478877583, 1478877874, 1478878195, 1478878485, 1478878777, 
1478879097, 1478879389, 1478879680, 1478880000, 1478880291, 1478880583, 
1478880874, 1478881195, 1478881485, 1478881777, 1478882097, 1478882389, 
1478882680, 1478883001, 1478883291, 1478883583, 1478883874, 1478884195, 
1478884485, 1478884777, 1478885097, 1478885389, 1478885680), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), capacidad = c(961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 
961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 
961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 
961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 
961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 961, 
961, 961, 961, 961), delta = c(-10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10, 10, 48, 432, -10, 10, 0, 10, -20, 10, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, -20, 0, 10, 0, -10, 10, -10, 10, 
-10, 10, -10, 10, 0, 0, -10, 0, 0, 10, -10, 10, 0, 0, 0, -19, 
9, 0), smoothValue = c(442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 
442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 442, 490, 912, 922, 
922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 
922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 
922, 922, 912, 912, 912, 912, 922, 922, 922, 922, 922, 912, 912, 
912)), .Names = c("sensorValue", "TimeStamp", "capacidad", "delta", 
"smoothValue"), row.names = 660:720, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... Are you just trying to get the length of runs of increment/decrement. Something like: `rle(diff(rnorm(20)) > 0)`

Comment: Not really, what i wanted to ask is how do i count the times when the tank was filled, and when the gas in the tank is being used, ignoring the normal expansion of the volume due to termal contraction or expansion.

Comment: could you search for delta being larger than some threshold (probably after cleaning the data to remove spikes)?

Comment: Yeah, the problem lies when i want to count one charge of gas and it´s composed by many contious deltas, meaning that the charge was made in more than 10 minutes, but  i want to count it as one single charge.

Comment: Well, merge 'charges' within 10 minutes? The user is not going to deplete it that fast and get a refill'

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, it looks like you want to count the number of runs when the level is falling or rising. We can use `diff` and `sign` to get a vector equal to -1 when the level is falling and 1 when the level is rising. Then we recode that to `Falling` and `Rising`, respectively. Finally, to count the number of periods with `Falling` or `Rising` level, we create a separate group for each run of `Falling` or `Rising` values.

```
library(dplyr)

# Fake data
set.seed(113)
dat = data.frame(sensorValue=cumsum(sample(c(-1,10),100,replace=TRUE,prob=c(10,1))) + 500, 
                 timeStamp=seq(0,495,5))
```

Here's what the fake data look like:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_classic())

ggplot(dat, aes(timeStamp, sensorValue)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

```
runs = with(dat, sign(diff(sensorValue)))
slope = recode(runs, "-1"="Falling", "1"="Rising")
groups = c(0, cumsum(diff(runs) != 0))

run.data = data.frame(runs, slope, groups)

run.data %>% group_by(groups) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  group_by(slope) %>% 
  tally
```

> ```
>     slope     n
> 1 Falling    11
> 2  Rising    10
> ```

**UPDATE:** Based on your comment, it looks like we need to do some filtering to get rid of small ups and downs in the data. You can get fancy and use a low pass filter to get rid of high frequency noise. But in this case, maybe a simpler approach will work.

In the code below, we calculate the difference between each successive measurement, just as before, but if the difference is less than 25, we set the difference to zero. You can adjust this cutoff value to whatever seems optimal for getting rid of the small noise jumps without eliminating the larger movements that you're interested in.

First, I've combined the two data samples you posted and added a new `time2` column that removes the time gap between the two samples, just for this illustration.

```
dat = rbind(dat, dat2)

# Put both data samples on a continuous 5-second time scale
dat$time2 = seq(0,nrow(dat)*5 - 5, 5)
```

Now we run the same code as before, but with the cutoff value of 25, below which we set the delta to zero.

```
runs = with(dat, sign(ifelse(abs(diff(sensorValue)) < 25, 0, diff(sensorValue))))
slope = recode(runs, "-1"="Falling", "0"="Stable", "1"="Rising")
groups = c(0, cumsum(diff(runs) != 0))

run.data = data.frame(runs, slope, groups)

run.data %>% group_by(groups) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  group_by(slope) %>% 
  tally
```

> ```
>     slope     n
>    <fctr> <int>
> 1 Falling     1
> 2  Rising     1
> 3  Stable     3
> ```

One large fall and one large rise seems to be consistent with the data sample:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(time2, sensorValue)) + 
  geom_line(size=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Almost, the problem now it's this:
1 Falling  1797
2  Rising   865
i expected much less risings and fallings and it's due to the 'noise' in the data.

Comment: Do you need to smooth your data first? If you post a larger data sample, it will be easier to provide code. Please paste into the body of your question the output of `dput(my_data[1:50,])` or some number of rows that will have at least one falling and rising period and that  exhibits the noise you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, i add two outputs, i hope this could help.